# How to get IProject Properties

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In Eclipse, when you right click a project and go to Properties, you can see all the Properties for that project. I want to be able to retrieve these properties with my `IProject`. Is there a good way to do this? I have looked into `IResource` and have been trying to figure out if I can use it to retrieve the properties. The `IResource` API can be found [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIResource.html)

Comment: If you mean everything in the tree on the left of the properties then no there is no way to get them all. The properties come from different plugins and each plugin may be using a different way to get the properties.

Comment: How about just a specific one?

Comment: You will have to look at source of the particular property page to see how it is getting the values. Even then it may be using internal only APIs. Use [Plugin Spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy) to find out what the property page is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each property page in the properties is provided by a property page class. This class can use any method that suits it to get the properties. So there is no general way to get all the properties.

You can study the source of an individual property page to see how it is getting the properties. However the API used may be an internal API which you should not use.

Use [Eclipse Plugin Spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy) to find out which class is displaying a particular property page:
[image: Example Plugin Spy]